# BlackBerry - How to develop in Eclipse using a lower SDK version

Tags: eclipse, blackberry, sdk

I am trying to develop a BlackBerry application. I have a BlackBerry 9700 with the OS version 4.6 installed on it.
So I have downloaded the latest version of the Eclipse Plugin (full version). However with this version I only can develop for the SDK 6.0. I want the app to be executed on my OS 4.6.

What do you recommand ? Should I install a new separated Eclipse with the 4.6 SDK ? If yes, where can I find the Eclipse Plugin using the 4.6 SDK, I didn't find it ? Is there a way to work in the same Eclipse ?
Or do you recommand to work on the SDK 6.0 using only 4.6 compatible APIs ? I tried to do that but I got an exception when I use the setExtent method on a 4.6 simulator (and don't get the exception on a 6.0 simulator).

I'm a bit ost with all those versions/eclipse/SDK/devices model/...

Thanks a lot for your help

Vincent

===========
EDIT:

I actually installed several BlackBerry SDK versions as described in the link you sent (using the install new software from the help menu of Eclipse). The installation went well and Eclipse restarted. When I go to Help->About Eclipse, I can see that BB SDK are installed.
However nothing else changed in Eclipse. I don't have any BlackBerry option when I click on New->Others (cannot create a new BB project), and when I go to Window->Preferences, I don't have any BlackBerry menu. The same for Run->Run configurations.
Blackberry appears nowhere in Eclipse except in the about menu.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install older component packs. You should be able to do that from Help -> Install new software.

For more details please see this document: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp

After installation, you can change the simulator and SDK from Run Configurations.

After that you can use the 4.6 SDK - the same program should work with both 4.6 and 6.0 (although note that there can be problems with touch screen - see http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/13222/Controlling_compatibility_mode_705034_11.jsp for more details.

Comment: thanks for your help. I still have a problem, I have edited my question to explain it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I think your setup is the issue...  Did you have a previous install of Eclipse?

Comment: I downloaded the last Eclipse Basic 3.6 release and freshly installed it. Then I used the update manager from the help menu.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you recommend ? I downloaded Eclipse Classic 3.6.2 (tried with 32 and 64 bits.

Comment: I finally used the Eclipse installation from the Eclipse Full Plugin for BlackBerry to add the other SDK versions, and it works. Thanks a lot for all your help.